# overwrite a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to overwrite the tik_id by using the function randomId so that I can generate random unique id, how can i do this??

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price=models.IntegerField()  
    tik_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcodes', blank=True) 

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.tik_id)

def randomId(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tikIdCode= ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for i in range(8))
```

Comment: BTW, for random IDs you're better off using a UUID of some sort - these are built into django :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use pass the method as `default` argument though `CharField`:

```
def generate_random_id():
    tikIdCode= ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for i in range(8))
    return tikIdCode

class Tickets(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price=models.IntegerField()  
    tik_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default=generate_random_id)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcodes', blank=True)
```

Comment: Careful you don't do it every time though and generate a new random ID every time you save the record (unless that's what you want of course!)